# R - How to add Column to dataframe with a variable for column title

Tags: r

I try to program a script in R, which should go through a dataframe looking for columns with formal/nominal entries. Finding such a column it should extract all entered values in a vector and add for each of those a column with binary data(0,1).

Problem: sign names to column with a variable `data$lev[z] <- data[,x]==lev[z]`  is not working. `lev[]` is a vector with names, `z` is an index for a loop.

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Please provide some reproducible example

Comment: @akrun

`letter <- c("a","b","c");
id <- c(1,2,3);
sample <- data.frame(id,letter);
y <- NCOL(sample);
x <- 0;
while ( x < y){
  x <- x+1;
  test01 <- is.factor(sample[,x]);
  if(test01 == TRUE ){
  lev <- levels(sample[,x]);
  q <- length(lev);
  z <- 0;
    while (z < q){
     z <- z+1;
      sample$lev[z] <- sample[,x]==lev[z];
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @AxelF put that into the quesiton itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only issue is that your last line should have `sample[,lev[z]]` rather than `sample$lev[z]`. As you currently have it (i.e. `sample$lev[z]`) you are telling R to assign a vector `(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)` to the `lev` column of `sample` in row `z`. In this example, you are trying to put 3 things into one place. Hence your warning message: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

A working code would be:

```
letter <- c("a","b","c")
id <- c(1,2,3)
sample <- data.frame(id,letter)
y <- NCOL(sample)
x <- 0
while ( x < y){ 
  x <- x+1
  test01 <- is.factor(sample[,x])
  if(test01 == TRUE ){ 
    lev <- levels(sample[,x])
    q <- length(lev)
    z <- 0
    while (z < q){ 
      z <- z+1
      sample[,lev[z]] <- sample[,x]==lev[z]
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: As an aside, getting used to `apply` functions can be very helpful for R. It allows you to do this kind of thing with much less code and it runs much faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. Sure you're right
We got a bonus assignment @univ and had only 3 weeks time to work it out. I had no prior experience in programming and/or R :D